# Stop highligtning Bar color in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

> I am using MPAndroidChart in my application. The problem is, whenever
>   I click any particular bar, it gets highlighted. I want to stop that
>   and want it to be normal as it was before get clicked.
>   I have tried these methods I found after doing study about it but nothing works fine:

```
    barChart.setClickable(false);
    barChart.setEnabled(false);
    barChart.setDrawHighlightArrow(false);
    barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    barChart.getData().setHighlightEnabled(false);
    barChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if the problem solved

`barchart.setTouchEnabled(false);`

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you brother. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable it via `BarDataSet` as explained [in project's wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Highlighting)

```
BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, null);
barDataSet.setHighlightEnabled(false);
```